# Complicated Integral of arccos

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

Let $R > r > 0$ be constants. I'm trying to work out the following integral:

$$ \int_{R-r}^R\arccos\bigg(\frac{\cosh(y)\cosh(r)-\cosh(R)}{\sinh(y)\sinh(r)}\bigg)\sinh(y)dy.$$

So far, I substituted $u = \cosh(y)$ to get

$$ \int_{\cosh(R-r)}^{\cosh(R)}\arccos\bigg(\frac{\cosh(r)u-\cosh(R)}{\sinh(r)\sqrt{u^2-1}}\bigg)dy,$$

but at this point I am stuck. I would be grateful for any hints or solutions!

Comment: The domain of $\arccos{(z)}$ is $-1\le z\le1$, but it looks to me like the expression inside the arccosine might be greater than one. Are you sure you didn’t mean to use the inverse *hyperbolic* cosine instead?